# Add option to CLI based on CMake configuration

Tags: c++, cmake, command-line-interface

I have written a program `prg` which can be run using bash with some subcommands like so

```
$ prg subcommand1
Output of subcomman1
$ prg subcommand2
Output of subcomman2
```

The program is written in C++11 and compiled with CMake (3.10+).

Now, I'd like to add another **optional** command, say `optional_subcommand`.
Optional - in a sense that a user can decide whether to compile program with it when configuring Cake.
To clarify, when the code is **not compiled** with`optional_subcommand` support, the output should be something along this lines

```
$ prg optional_subcommand
Option not supported...
```

The `optional_subcommand` requires external library to be installed. Hence `find_package(SomeLib REQUIRED)` must be invoked at some stage by CMake. The code for `optional_subcommand` requires this library to compile.

All I can think of is writing some dummy code for `optional_subcommand` which is then replaced on request by CMake. I think this can be achieved be asking CMake to overwrite, say `optional_subcommand.cpp` with either dummy or not.

Is proposed solution sensible or perhaps there is a better way to achieve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

CMake can define a preprocessor symbol and add extra files to your target (below, `prg`) if needed:

```
if(SomeLib_FOUND)
  target_compile_definitions(prg PUBLIC HAVE_SOMELIB)
  target_sources(prg PRIVATE src/optional_subcommand.cpp)
endif()
```

You can then wrap the command dispatching code for `optional_subcommand` with `#ifdef HAVE_SOMELIB`.